# Как назначить горячую клавишу в sublime text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3, hotkeys

Как узнать за что отвечает команда в sublime text 3 чтобы назначить это на горячую клавишу

```
{"keys": ["alt+ctrl+f"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false}}
```

По идее эта команда делает текст более читабельным (делает отступы)

У меня она не функционирует - что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Preferences - Key Bindings - User` - то что справа

Если файл пустой

```
 [
        { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+l"], "command": "reindent", "args": { "single_line": false } }
 ]
```

Если файл не пустой (втсавить через запятую)

```
  { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+l"], "command": "reindent", "args": { "single_line": false } }
```

**Команда `reindent` выравниват текст**

**О том как найти команду**:можно просто написать в гугле что делает команда и в результатах поиска будет название этой команды